# One column not vertically and horizontally centered

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I am trying to center the text in a table both vertically and horizontally. I thought I had managed to do so, but the last column is only centered horizontally. The code I am entering is

```
\documentclass[11 pt, a4paper, twoside]{report}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{table} [h]
\centering
\caption{}

\begin{tabular}{ | >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{3cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{3cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{4cm} | }
    \hline
    \rowcolor{lightgray} \textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Value} \\ [0.5cm]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

and it appears

[image]

Comment: (i) please always provide complete but small document beginning with `\documntclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` (ii) i cant reproduce your problem. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: @Zarko using `\documentclass{article}\usepackage[table]{xcolor}\usepackage{array}` as a preamble in TL2017 does reproduce the problem.

Comment: The issue is caused by the additional vertical skip in `\\[0.5cm]`. If you leave that `[0.5cm]` out, everything works fine.

Comment: @Skillmon but then I can't separate my rows? I only copied the first part of the table, so if I remove the "\\" I am not able to separate my rows.

Comment: @Rebecca you still use `\\ ` but without the optional argument `[0.5cm]`.

Answer (score 2):

For a solution which still uses `\rowcolor` and stuff see @AboAmmar's answer. But if you have the freedom of formatting your tables yourself, consider ditching the colours and vertical rules and use `booktabs`. Also text like in the "Description" column looks better, if it's left aligned. And consider using `p` columns instead of `m`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} [h]
\centering
\caption{}
\begin{tabular}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash} p{3cm} p{3cm} >{\centering\arraybackslash} p{4cm} }
  \toprule
    Variable & Description & Value \\
  \midrule
    Variable & Description which really needs the full width& Value \\
    Variable & Description & Value \\
    Variable & Description & Value \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And generally values shouldn't be that wide that you need multiple lines to format them. Instead consider using a `S`-type column provided by `siunitx` which horizontally aligns the numbers to have the same digits beneath each other (You need to hide the table header from that by enclosing it with `{Value}`). And variable names shouldn't be that wide, too, so perhaps use the `c` or the `l` specifier there. Additionally if each variable name is to be typeset in math-mode, you can use `>{\(}c<{\)}` to change that column to use math mode. A `\hbox` can be used to hide something from that effect (or `\text` provided by `amsmath`).

```
\documentclass[preview,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} [h]
\centering
\caption{}
\begin{tabular}{ >{\(}c<{\)} p{3cm} S }
  \toprule
  \hbox{Variable} & Description & {Value} \\
  \midrule
  x & Description which really needs the full width& 0.12 \\
  \sigma & Description & 10.51 \\
  \delta & Description & 15.43 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `\\[0.5cm]` to increase the first row height. This is the cause of misalignment in the last cell. You can use your own `\strut` to do this via a `$\vcenter{\hbox{\rule{0cm}{.5cm}}}$`, for example, or more easily by adding the `bigstrut` package and using its `bigstrut` macro.

Also, you can define `\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash} m{#1}}` for brevity and re-usability of your code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash} m{#1}}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{}
\begin{tabular}{ |C{3cm} |C{3cm} | C{4cm} | }
  \hline
  \rowcolor{lightgray} \textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Value}\bigstrut \\ \hline 
  Variable & Description & Value \\ \hline 
  Variable & Description & Value \\ \hline 
  Variable & Description & Value \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How would I do it if I want to set the size of the first row? I like the vertical spacing with \bigstrut so I want to use this on the rest of the rows, and then adjust the height of the first grey row.

Comment: @Rebecca -- Simply add this line before the table `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}`, this is equivalent to 20% more row height, you can change this to your need.